# How is component template transformed into template element

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm reading `ng-book` on angular2 and there is the following there:

> Template elements are special elements used to create views that can
>   be dynamically manipulated. In order to make working with templates
>   simpler, Angular provides some syntatic sugar to create templates, so
>   we often don’t create them by hand. For instance, when we write:
>
> ```
> <do-check-item
>         *ngFor="let comment of comments"
>         [comment]="comment"
>         (onRemove)="removeComment($event)">
> </do-check-item>
> ```
>
> This gets converted into:
>
> ```
> <do-check-item
>         template="ngFor let comment of comments; #i=index"
>         [comment]="comment"
>         (onRemove)="removeComment($event)">
> </do-check-item>
> ```
>
> Which then gets converted into:
>
> ```
> <template
>     ngFor
>     [ngForOf]="comments"
>     let-comment="$implicit"
>     let-index="i">
>     <do-check-item
>             [comment]="comment"
>             (onRemove)="removeComment($event)">
>     </do-check-item>
> </template>
> ```

But they don't define the rules the govern this transition. Can anyone explain or point to the relevant resource to read about the rules?

As I understand, all bindings are left on the component tag, while everything else is taken out and placed on the template element.

Comment: please read this link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#template might help you Angular inserts the template's content into the DOM when condition is true.